# Handle the count value returned from stored procedure in php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an stored procedure which returns the count value of a table like the following:

```
Create procedure procedure_name (parameters)
As Begin
-----
select @@ROWCOUNT AS Count
END
```

I am unaware about how to get the result of the sp in php.I know how to take the result if it is a table by using `mssql_num_rows(qry statement)`. I am unaware about how to handle the count returned.
I need to check the count for processing further.

My php code is like this:

```
$result_data = mssql_query("EXEC procedure_name parameter1,parameter2");
I need to get the count value here for processing.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the count as the return statement like the following

```
RETURN SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

In php, `$result_data = mssql_query("EXEC procedure_name parameter1,parameter2");`
the `$result_data` contains the count of the stored procedure.